# Create an x509 certificate using x509_cert? Work with ring?

Tags: rust, cryptography, x509certificate

I'm struggling to implement [the basic example in x509_cert](https://docs.rs/x509-cert/latest/x509_cert/builder/struct.CertificateBuilder.html):

```
use openssl::pkey::{PKey, Private};
use openssl::sign::Signer;
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::time::Duration;
use x509_cert::builder::{CertificateBuilder, Profile};
use x509_cert::name::Name;
use x509_cert::serial_number::SerialNumber;
use x509_cert::spki::SubjectPublicKeyInfoOwned;
use x509_cert::time::Validity;

fn test() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // Create a new RSA private key
    // let rsa = Rsa::generate(2048)?;
    // let key: PKey<Private> = PKey::from_rsa(rsa);

    let key: PKey<Private> = PKey::generate_ed25519()?;
    let public_key = key.raw_public_key()?;
    let public_key_der = key.public_key_to_der()?;

    let serial_number = SerialNumber::from(42u32);
    let validity = Validity::from_now(Duration::new(5, 0)).unwrap();
    let profile = Profile::Root;
    let subject =
        Name::from_str("CN=World domination corporation,O=World domination Inc,C=US").unwrap();

    let pub_key = SubjectPublicKeyInfoOwned::try_from(&public_key_der[..])?;
    let signer = Signer::new_without_digest(&key)?;
    // let signer = SigningKey::new(key);

    let builder =
        CertificateBuilder::new(profile, serial_number, validity, subject, pub_key, &signer)?;
}
```

I can't figure out how to get a signer that typechecks. In this version, I'm getting these errors:

```
the trait bound `Signer<'_>: spki::SignatureAlgorithmIdentifier` is not satisfied
the trait bound `Signer<'_>: signature::keypair::KeypairRef` is not satisfied
```

There exist methods in various libraries that create signatures, but I can't seem to get them to play nice with eachother.

Is there a way to get this to work? (openssl + x509_cert). Is there a way to get it to work with ring? Is there another crypto library I should be using?

Comment: would be nice if you share your cargo toml too, we can not know what version which features are on :)